# OpenVpn missing parameter tls-crypt config problem

Tags: debian, openvpn, vpn

I added a new user to my server and the .ovpn file seems to have so missing things which I can't understand. I have the same config with other keys and the same parameters for another machine and it works fine there. Here are the parameters.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 207.180.225.35 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
ignore-unknown-option block-outside-dns
block-outside-dns
tls-crypt
verb 3
<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#******************************************************************************************
(obfuscated)
#******************************************************************************************

-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
<cert>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
#******************************************************************************************
    (obfuscated)
#******************************************************************************************
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</cert>
<key>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
#******************************************************************************************
(obfuscated)
#******************************************************************************************
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
</key>
<tls-crypt>
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
#*********************************************
(obfuscated)
#*********************************************
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-crypt>
```

The error message is:

```
Sun Oct 27 16:37:34 2019 Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /home/vpnOrdner/upper.ovpn:13: block-outside-dns (2.3.9)
Options error: Unrecognized option or missing parameter(s) in /home/vpnOrdner/upper.ovpn:18: tls-crypt (2.3.9)
Use --help for more information.
```

The client machine runs Debian (openPli) and the server runs on Debian 10.

I tried deleting the line with "block-outside-dns" but it didn't fix the error with tls-crypt.

Comment: Have you tried to delete or comment the line with tls-crypt, because you have already the tls-crypt cert at the end.

Answer (score 4):

It seems you're using `OpenVPN 2.3.9`.

Options such as `block-outside-dns` and `tls-crypt` are available only in the `OpenVPN 2.4.x`.

You can upgrade your `OpenVPN` and use the same `.ovpn` file.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It worked after I removed openvpn 2.3, downloaded the openvpn 2.4 (.deb package) and installed it